# One tap login hide if I click outside of Iframe

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-client

I have integrated [Google On Tap Login](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web) in my website. What I want is that the iframe should not close until I click on the **X** icon on the header of I frame, yet by default it close if the user click anywhere on the page.

I want to disable the close of iframe if the user clicked outside of the iframe.

from the documentaion [[Toggle outside tap to close One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/toggle-outside-tap)
],You can disable this behavior when you set the `data-cancel_on_tap_outside` attribute with a value of `false`. unfortunately, this does not work.

Any help will be appreciate.

```
<div
    id="g_id_onload"
    data-client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-cancel_on_tap_outside=true
    >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, after clearing browser cache, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the cookie named "g_state" which keeps this status information.  No complete cache clear required.